# How to convert int[] to String []?

Tags: string, int

I am using trying to use toString(int[]) method, but I think I am doing it wrong:

```
int[] temp;
String[] vector
```

i try it:

```
vector =toString(temp[]);
```

Comment: Please add the programming language to the tags.

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
String[] vector= new String[temp.length];
int i = 0;
while (i < temp.length) {
    vector[i] = String.valueOf(temp[i++]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple but maybe not the best:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
{
   vector[i] = temp[i] + "";
}
```

Remember to check indexes so you don't get index out of bounds errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, it might just do the job

Vector = temp[].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

google guava:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

Lists.transform(Arrays.asList(temp),
                new Function<Integer, String>() {
                    public String apply(Integer i) {
                            return String.valueOf(i);
                    };
            }).toArray();
```